# Redis connection via domain name instead of IP: speed?

Tags: dns, redis

I was unable to find existing answers on this topic.

I am running a redis client that connects to a remote redis server (not on the same host).

I can connect either via the domain name or via the server's IP, i.e. I can launch the client either via `redis-cli -h 123.123.123.123` or `redis-cli -h my.domain.com`. It is more convenient to use the domain name.

Speed is important for my use case, therefore I would like to know whether the "costly" DNS lookup happens only once at startup or multiple times throughout the life of the client.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead will be paid only when a connection is established.

If you make sure that your application is keeping permanent connections to the Redis instances instead of systematically connecting/disconnecting, I would say the overhead is negligible.